# How to remove unwanted regions in a three-dimensional surface

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

As the title indicates, I want to delete some unwanted regions in a three-dimensional surface created using `ContourPlot3D`. Here is the corresponding code

```
Clear["Global`*"];

V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2 - x^2*y^2*z^2);

E0 = 7;

S0 = ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
PlotPoints -> 70, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], 
ImageSize -> 550]
```

which produces this output:

[image]

I want somehow to keep the inside closed 3D surface (which looks like a 3D star) and delete the eight open parts which surround it. I tried several combinations using `RegionPlot3D` but the particular range of $x$, $y$ and $z$ prevent me from obtaining what I want. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

If you increase the value of E0 then after a certain value the three-dimensional surface opens and eight channels of escapes (holes) appear. Using this code

```
Clear["Global`*"];

V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2 - x^2*y^2*z^2);

E0 = 8.5;
R0 = 6;

S0 = ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], 
ImageSize -> 550, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt@(x^2*y^2 + 
x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2) <= R0]]
```

you get this output

[image]

OK, my question is the following: How can I draw the surface and manipulate the openings at the minimum width. Let me be more specific. Now, using the current code the size of the openings is controlled by the cutoff surface and the particular value of $R0$. If for example, I use $R0 = 2.5$ then I loose essential parts of the surface.

[image]

What I want is to define such a cutoff surface or find the specific value of $R0$ so that the external cutoff surface to abut exactly against the inner surface thus, drawing the openings at their minimum width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Βαγγέλη, you can use an appropriate `RegionFunction`:

```
V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2 - 
     x^2*y^2*z^2);

E0 = 7;

S0 = ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 70, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  ImageSize -> 550, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 3 - Sqrt[x^2*y^2 + y^2 z^2] > 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**---EDIT---**

`RegionFunction` works like a cutoff. You need to find the equation of a curve that splits your wanted from your unwanted parts. Here

```
cutoff = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Sqrt[x^2*y^2 + y^2 z^2] == 3, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}];
Show[S0, cutoff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But how you'd guess it is a different issue. Normally manipulate your original surface. I.e. note that

```
cutoff2 = 
  ContourPlot3D[
   Sqrt@(x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2) == 4, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 
    4}, {z, -4, 4}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None];
Show[S0, cutoff2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

also works (in fact is a more obvious choice).

**---2nd EDIT---**

If you want to *qualitatively* see whether the containment of the surface is satisfactory, leave your `R0` variable and wrap a low-res version within a manipulate to see which value you like.

```
Manipulate[
 TableForm@{ContourPlot3D[
    V == E0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotPoints -> 40, 
    ContourStyle -> 
     Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], 
    ImageSize -> 550, 
    RegionFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt@(x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2) <= R0]], 
   R0}, {R0, 2, 6, 0.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to find the actual minimum, you'd have to find an expression for the intersection of the two surfaces, parametrise it, and minimize its length.

Comment: Great! Could you explain a little bit how this particular `RegionFunction` come from? I mean which theory is behind it.

Comment: When $V$ has another mathematical expression then the appropriate `RegionFunction` changes. However, I cannot understand how the function $3 - \sqrt{x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2} > 0$ come from. It is essential to me to know how to obtain this function every time. So, please enlighten me a little bit!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z If you have a surface like yours that is a generalised "sphere" in that you can permute any two cartesian coordinates and get the same expression, you need to define your cutoff as something with larger radius or slightly deformed. Does that help?

Comment: Yes indeed, now everything is very clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any ideas about my EDIT? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: does the edit help?

Comment: Using `Manipulate` you can have a quick and rough estimation about the correct value of $R0$. However, I think that the theoretical approach through the intersection of the two surfaces is the best one. So, could you post an example of it?

Comment: Actually, no, I'm sorry. It will take me more time than I can afford right now and it's getting to the point that it has become a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the hyperbolic behavior of the branches, you may try a simple `RegionFunction[]`:

```
ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 70, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], ImageSize -> 550, 
  RegionFunction -> (Abs[#1 #2 #3] < 3 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Just checking the whole solid is included

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 70, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  ImageSize -> 550, RegionFunction -> (Abs[Times[#1 #2 #3]] < 3 &)], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Abs[3/(x y)]}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 70, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

For giggles, here's a variation of belisarius's answer:

```
ContourPlot3D[V == E0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
              ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3, Green], Specularity[1, 30]], 
              Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotPoints -> 70, 
              RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[
   PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "RegionFunction"][Sqrt[2] x/9, Sqrt[2] y/9, Sqrt[2] z/9]]]]
```